# My while loop should be running until the user wants to stop it but ends after the 2nd input

Tags: python, input, while-loop, append

I feel like the question is not well worded for a question, but this is what I really want:

I am writing this code where a 'user' can enter as many integers from 1 to 10 as he/she wants. Every time after the user has entered an integer, use a yes/no type question to ask whether he/she wants to enter another one. Calculate and display the average of the integers in the list.

Isn't 'while' supposed to running part of a program over and over and over again until it stops when it is told not to?

```
num_list = []
len()
integer_pushed = float(input("Enter as many integers from 1 to 10"))
num_list.append(integer_pushed)
again = input("Enter another integer? [y/n]")


while integer_pushed < 0 or integer_pushed > 10:
    print('You must type in an integer between 0 and 10')
    integer_pushed = float(input("Enter as many integers from 1 to 10"))
    num_list.append(integer_pushed)
    again = input("Enter another integer? [y/n]")

while again == "y":
    integer_pushed = float(input("Enter as many integers from 1 to 10"))
    num_list.append(integer_pushed)
    again = input("Enter another integer? [y/n]")
    print ("Number list:", num_list)

while again == "y":
    integer_pushed = float(input("Enter as many integers from 1 to 10"))
    num_list.append(integer_pushed)
    again = input("Enter another integer? [y/n]")
    print ("Number list:", num_list)
```

It stops after the 2nd time even if the user types in 'y'. It then gives me the 'Number List: ".

Once again, you guys have been great assisting my classmates and I. Im in an introduction to Python course and we are learning about loops and lists.

Comment: Why do you have the `while again == 'y':` loop repeated twice?

Comment: Also this code seems to be working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `while` loop is sufficient to achieve what you want.

```
num_list = []
again = 'y'

while again=='y':
    no = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
    if not 1 <= no <= 10:
        continue
    num_list.append(no)
    again = input("Enter another? [y/n]: ")

print("Average: ", sum(num_list) / len(num_list))
```

The `while` loop runs as long as `again == 'y'`. The program asks for another number if the user inputs an integer not between 1 and 10.

Comment: I really like this code because you showed me that I need is one 'while' to loop and loop until the user says 'n'. Really easy to understand and you really cleaned up my garbage code. Thank you so much nisemonoxide

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
num_list = []
again = "y"
while again == "y":
    try:
        integer_pushed = float(input("Enter as many integers from 1 to 10"))
        if integer_pushed > 0 or integer_pushed <= 10:
            num_list.append(integer_pushed)
            again = input("Enter another integer? [y/n]")
            print("Number list:", num_list)
        else: 
            print('You must type in an integer between 0 and 10')
    except ValueError:
        print('You must type in an integer not a str')
```

I'm not sure why you had two different while loops, let alone three. However, this should do what you want. It will prompt the user for a number, and try and convert it to a float. If it can't be converted, it will prompt the user again. If it is converted it will check to see if it's between 0 and 10 and if it is, it will add it to the list, otherwise, it will tell the user that that's an invalid number.